# Odd XCode 4.2 & Core Data Behavior

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So I recently upgraded to XCode 4.2, in part because I needed the IOS 5 SDK.

Anyhow, when I compiled and attempted to run my app, I found that it would no longer run. This is due to the fact that an attribute in a Core Data entity is now somehow marked as read only.

I did not do this, and I can find no evidence of this other than the error message.

In my core data managed object, called Note:

```
@interface Note : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
...


@implementation Note
@dynamic title;
...
```

Later - and elsewhere - in the code, I attempt to do this:

```
self.note.title=self.noteTitle.text;
```

When execution gets to this line, I receive these errors:

```
Property 'title' is marked readonly on class 'Note'.  Cannot generate a setter method for it.
-[Note setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80ae3d0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Note setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80ae3d0'
```

What the ???? I could just hand-code the setter - the error says it cannot generate one for me - but I'd really like to understand what happened here.

I did regenerate the managed object files for this entity, which did not work. I created a new  data model, too, and checked to make sure nothing was set that shouldn't be.

Edit: I left out what turned out to be an important tidbit: I have a category defined on Note (the managed object). In the category, I added a protocol to the object (MKAnnotation). My category was defined thusly:

```
@interface Note (Extras) <MKAnnotation>
```

I had since removed the 'need' for the protocol, but did not remove the reference. When I did, everything went back to the way it should be.

So while I've solved my problem, I'm left wondering: Is it bad behavior to add a protocol to a managed object?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to rename the 'title' attribute to something else? Sometimes I receive error messages, when using certain attribute names. Perhaps try it with noteTitle.

Comment: Well, I could. It was working great until the upgrade. I suppose it's possible apple made a change to the list of reserved words, but in a relatively minor version change?

Comment: I fixed this. I didn't mention everything I should have, probably. I've edited the question to include the extra info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MKAnnotation` protocol has a readonly `title` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title
```

.. which conflicts with your dynamic property by the same name.

(Source: [Apple, MKAnnotation Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html))

Answer (score 2):

It is not bad to add protocols to a `NSManagedObject`; there are many reasons why you would want to.